# Linq Enumerable gives NullReferenceException in IE 9. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Am developing a web-application in ASP.NET (C#) and following code snippet is part of a function:

```
string[] paramList = new string[2];
string[] paramValList = new string[2];

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(paramXML);
var oParamCollection = from parameters in doc.Descendants("myfunction")
          select new
          {
          Name = parameters.Attribute("myParam").Value,
          Value = parameters.Attribute("myParamValue").Value
          };

int i=0;
foreach (var oParam in oParamCollection)
{
    string name = oParam.Name.Trim();
    string value = oParam.Value.Trim();

    paramList[i] = oParam.Name.Trim();
    paramValList[i++] = oParam.Value.Trim();

    if (i >= 2)
    break;
}
```

Following is the value of paramXML variable (parameter) being used at the 3 code-line:

```
<root><myfunction myparam=" DeliveryDate" myparamvalue="2012-07-01" ></myfunction></root>
```

Now the issue is that when I open my web-application in Chrome or Firefox, there is not error but when I use it in IE 9 (in same state and with same development environment), I get **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object** at the start of foreach loop. While debugging, I checked the value of **oParamCollection** in QuickWatch while using in Chrome or FireFox and I get the count as 1 but when I checked the value while using the application in IE 9, the count gives the exception. Am so much confused. Have spent quite sometime on internet searching for this problem but no pointer till now. SO is my last hope. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @jeroenh, I have already mentioned the value of paramXML in my question. And also as I mentioned, the code is working perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: and paramXML is the same with IE, chrome and ff?

Comment: @jeroenh: Yes, have checked the value and its same in IE, Chrome & FF.

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) or similar to see what's different about what's going over the wire, in the different cases.

Comment: There are no descendant nodes named `spparam` in your paramXML, so clearly there's incomplete info here.

Comment: @jeroenh: Am extremely sorry for that typo. Have updated the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of debugging, finally I have found the solution. The problem is surely in the code snippet (due to my silly mistake) mentioned in the question. The problematic code is as follows:

```
            var oParams = from parameters in l_oXDoc.Descendants("myfunction")
                          select new
                          {
                              //Name = (string) parameters.Attribute("myParam"),
                              //Value = (string) parameters.Attribute("myParamValue")
                              Name = parameters.Attribute("myParam").Value,
                              Value = parameters.Attribute("myParamValue").Value
                          };
```

The issue was that the XML string had the attribute names `myParam` and `myParamValue` in lowercase whereas here in code I was checking in camel case. The problem got resolved the moment I changed it to 'myparam' and 'myparamvalue' into lower case in my code. My rectified code is as follows:

```
            var oParams = from parameters in l_oXDoc.Descendants("myfunction")
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = parameters.Attribute("myparam").Value,
                              Value = parameters.Attribute("myparamvalue").Value
                          };
```

But my doubt still remains the same, why it happens only for IE and not while using Chrome or FF? I request respectable members of SO to try this and check it on their own.

I would like to thank **Jon Skeet** for giving me a pointer (+1 for you). @Jon, it my case, the Value property works for attribute. If you have any reference to cases where the Value may not work, please do share it with me. Thank you.

Comment: I am marking this as answer so that if anyone, in future, faces such issues knows what part of code look at to resolve it.

Comment: There's no point in requesting that people try something without telling them what to try. Try reading this question again, pretending you have no idea of any context other than what's in the question. How exactly would you try it? What information are you missing? Now provide that information.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that for some reason when using IE9, you don't have those attributes in all cases. (You say you've presented the value of `paramXML`, but I *strongly* suspect it isn't the same when the client is IE9 as it is in the working cases. That's the only reason your code would fail.)

You can *hide* the problem by casting `XAttribute` to `string` instead of using the `Value` property:

```
var oParamCollection = from parameters in doc.Descendants("spparam")
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = (string) parameters.Attribute("myParam"),
                           Value = (string) parameters.Attribute("myParamValue")
                       };
```

Now you won't get an exception... but you'll have to cope with having `null` values for `Name` or `Value` if the corresponding attribute isn't present.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I have told earlier the string value in paramXML is same in all the browsers along with the attributes. Also, the Name and Value attributes will always be present as they are generated by a function which either results in empty string if no records in DB or atleast 1 XML node in string with Name and Value. This function in turn calls another function is having the piece of code that I have mentioned in my question. Now, as you suggested, I will try casting the attributes as string and let you know if that works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shant: I'm afraid I simply don't believe you - I suspect you have misdiagnosed that side of things. The fact that `Count()` gives you an exception *strongly* suggests an attribute is missing. It's not like your code is *running* in the client - the only way the client can affect this is in the data that it presents.

Comment: you may not buy my reply but I must say that the problem which I had reported may not logically make sense but the problem lies the same. Try the piece of code in my question and try to read values of attributes with difference case (having string XML completely in lower case as compared to upper or camel case for attribute names in LINQ statment) and you will find that the behavior between Chrome and IE is different. While using Chrome or FF, I get the values where as if I use IE, I don't. Let me know, if you have any solution on this, coz as I said the problem do exists.

Comment: @Shant: Nothing you've provided would interact with a browser. Either the XML has an attribute name of `myParamValue` or it has a name of `myparamvalue`. You *still* haven't explained how the XML gets to your program. What **exactly** am I meant to test in Chrome and IE? You haven't provided even slightly enough for us to be able to reproduce it. If you can provide a lot more detail, I'm happy to look further - but so far, you've just given some XML and some C# code. I can run that C# code in a console app, but that clearly has nothing to do with Chrome or IE...

Comment: The XML gets generated by a function written in C# which reads values from a table for given value of ID column. If there are no rows, the XML string is completely EMPTY where as if there is 1 or more rows, the XML string gets generated. Let me know, if you want to publish that function here.

Comment: @Shant: That doesn't tell me anything about where the browser comes into play. How would the XML vary based on which browser you're using? Because the behaviour of LINQ to XML on the server side certainly won't vary by browser...

Comment: Got it. I will logically frame my problem with exact scenario once again for you. And I do really appreciate and thank you for talking over it in going deep to the root cause of the issue even though I got my issue sorted out. :)

Comment: Can I drop a mail explaining the functionality as it may not fit in comments box? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Shant: Yes, sure. Mail skeet@pobox.com